# how to make BottomNavigationBar with number and text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to build a BottomNavigationBar with a text and a number as the photo below :

[image]

- the name of the tab is will shown just when the app is active

how to do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Basically this is exactly what you want: https://flutterawesome.com/a-modern-google-style-nav-bar-for-flutter/

I recomend you extracting this code and build it to your fits.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:line_icons/line_icons.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "GNav",
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.grey[800],
    ),
    home: Example()));

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Likes',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: Search',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 3: Profile',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 20, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1))
        ]),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8),
            child: GNav(
                gap: 8,
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 24,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
                tabs: [
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.home,
                    text: 'Home',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.heart_o,
                    text: 'Likes',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.search,
                    text: 'Search',
                  ),
                  GButton(
                    icon: LineIcons.user,
                    text: 'Profile',
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTabChange: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Link to repository and full code:
https://github.com/sooxt98/google_nav_bar

Comment: I need to ask you, can I put a small number in any icon using this package?